# Prolog - creating a new list of the elements from an original list after doubling each value?

Tags: list, prolog

[Example of trace produced.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/490lR.png)   I'm trying to write a predicate, `listDouble(L1, L2)`, where every element in `L2` is the double of its corresponding element in `L1` (i.e. if L1 = [1, 2, 3] then L2 = [2, 4, 6]), and this is my code so far:

```
listDouble([], [L2]).
listDouble([H|T], [L2|_]):-
        L is H * 2,
        listDouble(T, [L]).
```

However, it's not working and I think I'm struggling to understand how to add the double of each element to `L2`?

Comment: Are you not getting singleton variable warnings? The structure looks ok, you just need to re-think the distribution of the variable names.

Comment: @TomasBy  I am getting a few singleton variable warnings - but I thought that might have been because I wasn't structuring it right. L2 is meant to be a list of the elements in L1 but each element is doubled.. i.e. if L1 = [1, 2, 3] then L2 = [2, 4, 6]

Comment: Well, they are warnings, but they ususally indicate fatal errors in Prolog. I understand the problem I think, I was just trying to get you to realise that there is a problem in the base case.

Comment: And why do you expect to always get a list with exactly one element back in the recursive call?

Comment: @TomasBy  I thought it made sense to have an empty list as the base because I recurse through L1 anyway and when I'd gone through L1, L2 would be holding the elements which were now doubled. And yes I think that's a mistake - is should be [L2] instead of just L2?

Comment: But how many elements is it that are doubled if the input list is empty?

Comment: @TomasBy well no elements.. I've added a trace example output if that helps?

Comment: This is so trivial that I don't think tracing is needed. How do you write no elements, instead of `L2`...

Comment: well it would just be an empty list?? [ ]

Answer (score 1):

```
listDouble([],[]).
listDouble([H|T], [D|L]):-
        D is H * 2,
        listDouble(T,L).
```

Comment: @Carol this is a very common pattern in Prolog, to recurse through a list and map its elements to a corresponding list. So, there's an ISO predicate called `maplist` that will do this for you. If you define a predicate that doubles a value, you can then use `maplist`. For instance, `double(X, D) :- D is X * 2.` and `listDouble(List, DList) :- maplist(double, List, DList).`